# how to find frequency of the keys in a dictionary across multiple text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I am supposed to count the frequency of all the key values of dictionary "d" across all the files in the document "individual-articles' 
Here,the document "individual-articles' has around 20000 txt files,with filenames 1,2,3,4...
for ex: suppose  d[Britain]=[5,76,289]  must return the number of times Britain appears in the files 5.txt,76.txt,289.txt belonging to the document "induvidual articles", and also i need to find its frequency across all the files in the same document. i need to store these values in another d2
for the same example,
d2 must contain (Britain,26,1200) where 26 is the frequency of the word Britain in the files 5.txt,76.txt and 289.txt and 1200 is the frequency of the word Britain in all the files.
I am a python newbie, and i have tried little! please help!!

```
import collections
import sys
import os
import re
sys.stdout=open('dictionary.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob
def removegarbage(text):
    text=re.sub(r'\W+',' ',text)
    text=text.lower()
    sorted(text)
    return text


folderpath='d:/individual-articles'
counter=Counter()


filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))


d2={}
with open('topics.txt') as f:
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        value, *keys = line.strip().split('~')
        for key in filter(None, keys):
            d[key].append(value)

for filepath in filepaths:
    with open(filepath,'r') as filehandle:
        lines = filehandle.read()
        words = removegarbage(lines).split()
        for k in d.keys():
            d2[k] = words.count(k)

for i in d2.items():
    print(i)
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with our code?

Comment: the counting is wrong i guess, coz d2 shows 0 for all the key values' frquencies

Comment: In the line `d2[k] = data.count(k)`, what is `data` ?

Comment: sorry, i edited it, its "words"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by all the files in the document "X" but I assume it's analogous to pages in a book. With this interpretation, I would do my best to store the the data in the easiest way. Putting data in easily manipulable adds efficiency later, because you can always just add a method for accomplishing and type of output you want.

Since it seems the main key you're looking at is keyword, I would create a nested python dictionary with this structure

```
dict = (keyword:{file:count})
```

Once it's in this form, you can do any type of manipulation on the data really easily.

To create this dict,

```
import os
# returns the next word in the file
def words_generator(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word
word_count_dict = {}
for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk("./"):
    for file in fnames:
        f = open(file,"r")
        words = words_generator(f)
        for word in words:
            if word not in word_count_dict:
                  word_count_dict[word] = {"total":0}
            if file not in word_count_dict[word]:
                  word_count_dict[word][file] = 0
            word_count_dict[word][file] += 1              
            word_count_dict[word]["total"] += 1
```

This will create an easily parsable dictionary.

Want the number of total words Britain?

```
word_count_dict["Britain"]["total"]
```

Want the number of times Britain is in files 74.txt and 75.txt?

```
sum([word_count_dict["Britain"][file] if file in word_count_dict else 0 for file in ["74.txt", "75.txt"]])
```

Want to see all files that the word Britain shows up in?

```
[file for key in word_count_dict["Britain"]]
```

You can of course write functions that perform these operations with a simple call.

Comment: but i want it for all the keys, not just a particular one,in this case "Britain", so how do i run a loop for all the key values in the dict?

Comment: how do i store all these values in another dictionary?

Comment: for key in word_count_dict: will iterate through all the keys in the dictionary. If you want special values in another dictionary, just make it a for loop. For example, this is how you would make a dictionary with just the totals:

    totals_dict = {}
    for key in word_count_dict:
        totals_dict[key] = word_count_dict[key][totals]

You can make the right side of that quality anything.